# What does "tracks targets" mean in the description of recon scopes?

Tags: fallout-4

I noticed the option to craft Recon Scopes for certain weapons which requires a higher level of Gun Nut than I currently have. The description mentiones "tracks targets" as one benefit of the mod, what exactly does this do?

Comment: was wondering also. Side note: when searching I noted that people experience a glitch where the shader effect does not go away even after unequipping it. There is a console command to rectify that.

Answer (score 10):

It means that when you target an enemy through that scope it will paint the target (draw a diamond above its head) letting you track it.

[image: track targets]

Comment: Useful note: Once painted, the diamond sticks on the target even when you switch out of the scope or change weapons. I haven't tested with fast-travel or just running far away and coming back, but it seems the only thing that normally clears it is killing the enemy.